# A simple loop for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to ask question about loops in python. I want to reduce the value of two variable ( a and b) alternatively in one loop.

The  output I want is as follow:

```
a    b
20  20
19  20
19  19
18  19
```

I have tried while and for loops but I can't find a simple and easy way to reduce **alternatively** of one variable in a loop. Is there a simple way to change the value of variable in one loop.

Comment: Please post your best attempt. This should be simple, so I'm not sure where you're going wrong. I'm also not quite sure what the initial value is and how it changes. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave this a try. See if it works for you!

```
a = 20
b = 21
for i in range(0, 40):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        b -= 1
    else:
        a -= 1
    print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
20 20
19 20
19 19
18 19
18 18
17 18
17 17
16 17
16 16
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement something similar. For example, you can use an if statement inside your loop where `if a == b`, subtract `a`, otherwise subtract `b` so `a` and `b` are now alternating.

Since not a lot of details was provided, a very basic loop that would fit your example can look like this:

```
a = 20
b = 20

while a > 0: #assuming an end condition here
    if b > 18: print(a, b) #to match the output in the question, not necessary for code to work

    if a == b:
        a -= 1
    else:
        b -= 1
```

Of course, there are many other ways as well. If there are more details provided, a better solution can likely be found!

Comment: Note that to get OP's desired output, you need to do `while b > 18: print(a, b); ...`

Comment: Haha of course. That's a good point I did not consider. Edited to reflect that!

Answer (score 0):

You can shift between reducing `a` or `b` by keeping track of a flag here named `change` :

```
a = b = 4
change = True

# we multiplied by two to cover whole range.
for i in range(2 * a):
    print(a, b)

    if change:
        a -= 1
        change = False
    else:
        b -= 1
        change = True
```

output :

```
4 4
3 4
3 3
2 3
2 2
1 2
1 1
0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
a,b=20,20

print(f'a\tb')

for i in range(4):
    print(f'{a}\t{b}')
    a,b=(a-1,b) if i%2==0 else (a,b-1)
```

Prints:

```
a   b
20  20
19  20
19  19
18  19
```